# Como usar o @Html.ValidationMessageFor para mudar a classe da caixa de texto

Tags: c#, css, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-5

Eu comprei um template bootstrap, a validação dos controles é feita por uma classe que deixa os controles vermelhos. Essa seriam as classes `form-group has-error`

Só que eu nunca usei dessa forma, estou acostumado a usar o código gerado por ele mesmo:
Exemplo:

```
@Html.EditorFor(model => model.Campo, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Campo, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
```

E aí o validator escreve a mensagem de erro se o objeto voltar com erro.

No controle uso o padrão `if (ModelState.IsValid)`

Como eu posso fazer para transformar a classe? Se não der para usar o `ValidationMessageFor`, como eu poderia fazer?

ATUALIZAÇÃO:

Eu quero mudar a classe do textbox e não exibir uma mensagem.

Answer (score 1):

Você pode apenas adicionar a classe a seu `@html.ValidationMessageFor()`, ficando assim:

```
@Html.EditorFor(model => model.Campo, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
@Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Campo, "", new { @class = "form-group has-error" })
```

Olhe [esse exemplo no .NET Fiddle.](https://dotnetfiddle.net/OmSCiS)

Nele estou adicionando a class error a minha validação, deixando a fonte com `25px` utilizando essa classe:

```
.error{
    font-size: 25px;
}
```

Comment: Então, é quase isso! Só que em vez de aparecer uma mensagem eu gostaria que ele apenas circulasse o textbox com uma linha vermelha. (naõ precisa ter css para isso, só quero saber como mudar a classe do <div class="form-group">